# LSTM NN: forward propagation

Tags: neural-network, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to neural nets, and am creating a LSTM from scratch.  I have the forward propagation working...but I have a few questions about the moving pieces in forward propagation in the context of a trained model, back propagation, and memory management.

So, right now, when I run forward propagation, I stack the new columns, `f_t, i_t, C_t, h_t, etc` on their corresponding arrays as I accumulate previous positions for the bptt gradient calculations.

My question is 4 part:

1) **How far back in time do I need to back propagate in order to retain reasonably long-term memories?** (memory stretching back 20-40 time steps is probably what I need for my system (although I could benefit from a much longer time period--that is just the minimum for decent performance--*and I'm only shooting for the minimum right now, so I can get it working*)

2) **Once I consider my model "trained," is there *any* reason for me to keep more than the 2 time-steps I need to calculate the next `C` and `h` values?** (where `C_t` is the Cell state, and `h_t` is the final output of the LSTM net)  *in which case I would need multiple versions of the forward propagation function*

3) **If I have limited time series data on which to train, and I want to train my model, will the performance of my model *converge* as I train it on the training data over and over (as versus oscillate around some maximal average performance)?  And will it converge if I implement dropout?**

4) **How many components of the gradient do I need to consider?  When I calculate the gradient of the various matrices, I get a primary contribution at time step t, and secondary contributions from time step t-1 (and the calculation recurses all the way back to t=0)?** (in other words: does the primary contribution dominate the gradient calculation--will the slope change due to the secondary components enough to warrant implementing the recursion as I back propagate time steps...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you have observed, it depends on the dependencies in the data. But LSTM can learn to learn longer term dependencies even though we back propagate only a few time steps if we do not reset the cell and hidden states.
2. No. Given c_t and h_t, you can determine c and h for the next time step. Since you don't need to back propagate, you can throw away c_t (and even h_t if you are just interested in the final LSTM output)
3. You might converge if you start over fitting. Using Dropout will definitely help avoiding that, especially along with early stopping.
4. There will be 2 components of gradient for h_t - one for current output and one from the next time step. Once you add the both, you won't have to worry about any other components